# Excel signing off and locking a row

Tags: excel, locking, signing

I am developing a sheet for work. When staff complete a row either myself or my manager need to be able to put our names in column J in order to lock the respective rows to prevent further editing. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First Unlock EVERY cell in the sheet. Then Protect the Sheet.

Next add this code to the Worksheet Events Module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range
If Target.Column = 4 Then 'IF Changed cell is in Column D
    For Each C In Target.Cells
        If C.Value = "YourName" Or C.Value = "YourManagersName" Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect 

            C.EntireRow.Locked = True

            ActiveSheet.Protect 
        End If
    Next C
End If

End Sub
```

Now if one of the 2 names is entered in the specific column then it will Lock that row.

If you want a Password use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range
If Target.Column = 4 Then 'IF Changed cell is in Column D
    For Each C In Target.Cells
        If C.Value = "YourName" Or C.Value = "YourManagersName" Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"

            C.EntireRow.Locked = True

            ActiveSheet.Protect "Password"
        End If
    Next C
End If

End Sub
```

***NOTE:*** This will also allow you to lock multiple rows in one shot.